# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю,почему возникает такая ошибка,в postman запрос по такому же url работает как надо

```
const mainpage_url = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:5000/api/goods_list";

   fetch(mainpage_url)
    .then((response)=>{
     return response.json();
    })
    .then((response)=>{
      goodsListData=response
     })

     export default goodsListData;
```

index.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import router from "./router.js";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";


 const PORT = 5000;

 const = DB_URL="mongodb+srv://SmirnoffSkutte:is280268@cluster0.ouf3u.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"



   const app = express();
   const cors = require('cors');

  var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:3000'
  };

 app.use(cors(corsOptions))


  app.use(express.json())

  app.use(express.static('static'))

  app.use(fileUpload({}))

  app.use('/api',router)




    async function startApp(){
      try{
        mongoose.connect(DB_URL,{useNewUrlParser:true})
          app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('AMOGUS sus fewfew'))

       } catch(e) {

        console.log(e)

       }
  }

  startApp()
```

Comment: некорректный `url`.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте корректную ссылку.

```
const mainpage_url = "http://localhost:5000/api/goods_list";
```

Если необходимо передать нужные заголовки, то передавайте их вторым параметром в `fetch()`

```
fetch(mainpage_url, {
  headers: {
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'http://localhost:5000/api/goods_list'
  }
}))
```

Comment: Извините,но не работает,он теперь пишет,что не может прочитать cors и нет Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @IvanSmirnoff, потому что заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` выставляет сервером, а не клиентом

Comment: @Grundy Извините за беспокойство,не подскажите, нужно в бэкэнде в index.js написать что-то вроде такого? var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:3000'
    };
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

Comment: @IvanSmirnoff, может зависеть от того, что именно ты используешь на сервере, но да, похоже на правду

Comment: @Grundy А что нужно использовать,что бы это работало?

Comment: @IvanSmirnoff, а у тебя это не работает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133877/discussion-between-ivan-smirnoff-and-grundy).

Comment: @Grundy не работает